# IBM Bluemix application migration issue

Tags: migration, cloud, ibm-cloud, sql-loader

I have an application which has batch job which reads file from an application server (the file will be placed by a daily job from another batch job in the application server) and writes to the database. Also, for this batch job to run successfully it requires an Oracle client and persistent storage to process this 600MB file.

At On-premises, the existing flow is something like this:

- Host job will place a file in the server folder path.
- Daily job will execute `sqlloader` Oracle command to pump the large data generated from the host job into the database.

Oracle client is installed in the server to execute `sqlloader` command. The command expects physical file location.

Now, am in the process of migrating into

Since am about to migrate to the IBM Cloud Bluemix (Private IaaS) cloud, how can I overcome the physical location of the file issue?

Comment: What about uploading the file first to the IBM Bluemix Object Storage?

Comment: If it's IaaS, is this actually a problem?